# Generate int for Arraylist<entry> for position

Tags: java, android, arraylist, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i have a problem with an arraylist of a graphic. I popolate the first parameter of entry with date from firebase. I must set the second parameter with int for the position in graph. There is a method to generate an int from 0 to number of item? I hope I was clear, if not I'll explain better.

```
mPostReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
   @Override
   public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

     final LineChart lineChart = (LineChart) findViewById(chart);

     final ArrayList<Entry> entries = new ArrayList<>();


     final LineDataSet dataset = new LineDataSet(entries, "# of Calls");
     final ArrayList<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();
     labels.clear();


     for (DataSnapshot data: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
      final Specialita_2 specialita = data.getValue(Specialita_2.class);

      String results = specialita.result;

      if (results != null) {
       results = results.replace(",", "");
       results = results.replace(".", "");
      }

      if (specialita.id != null && specialita.date != null && specialita.result != null) {

       labels.add(specialita.date);
       entries.add(new Entry(Integer.parseInt(results), -- - here the int for position____));

      }
      Long childrenCount = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
      String s_count = String.valueOf(childrenCount);
      TextView t = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
      t.setText(s_count);

     }
```

Comment: get childerncount from snapshot and generate int[] from that

Comment: But getChildrenCount don't give me only 1 number? Total of item?

Comment: Why not use the current size of the list?

Comment: how do I build an int starting from size list? I take dates directly from firebase, not from list.

Comment: Sorry, I may be misunderstanding your problem but: entries.add(new Entry(Integer.parseInt(results), entries.size()));  would give each entry an integer value equal to its index in the list. Is this not the same as the position of the result in the source data?

Comment: ahhh!!!! entries.size() work pefectly. it was so simple, i did't think this solution. thanks jonathan essex for help!